# Fastest way to create a symmetric matrix in python, with elements as below

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, jupyter-notebook

I have a collection of arrays
`K0,K1,K2....Kn` defined over a 1D array `z`

I want the following symmetric matrix in the fastest way possible without using for loop.

```
    [np.trapz(K0*K0,z)  np.trapz(K0*K1,z)  np.trapz(K0*K2,z)  np.trapz(K0*K3,z)...]
    [      .            np.trapz(K1*K1,z)  np.trapz(K1*K2,z)  np.trapz(K1*K3,z)...]
A = [      .                    .          np.trapz(K2*K2,z)  np.trapz(K2*K3,z)...]
    [      .                    .             .               np.trapz(K3*K3,z)...]
    [      .                    .             .                       .           ]
```

Below is the fastest I could manage (still not fast enough for large n... `n>10000`).

I store those set of `K`s in a combined array called `KK`

```
KK = []
for i in range(n):
    KK.append(Ki)
KK = np.array(KK)
```

```
A = np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(n):
    A[i,i:] = A[i:,i] = np.trapz((KK[i]*KK[i:]),z)
```

What is a faster way to do it? I don't care how inelegant or non-pythonic the solution is. I just want to ramp up the speed.

Comment: It seems you are mixing here math and Python notation. Better use Python notation only. How exactly is "KK" created?

Comment: Made the changes. I understand K0(z) etc makes you think K0 is a function. But I'm not able to accurately represent these quantities without LateX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the properties of symmetric, matrix making it very efficient. One way to speed up is to use [Numba](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/installing.html)

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(cache=True, nogil=True, parallel=True)
def fun(KK,z,n):
    A = np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in nb.prange(n):
        A[i,i:] = A[i:,i] = np.trapz((KK[i]*KK[i:]),z)
    return A
```

**Old answers**

```
np.trapz(KK.T[:,:,None]@KK.T[:,None,:],z,axis=0) # using matrix multiplication

np.trapz(np.einsum('ik,jk->ijk',KK,KK),z,axis=2) # Using einsum
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers. These are taking much longer than my for loop attempt though.

Comment: @PrasadMani How large your n's and numbers of z's ? It depends on how well the memory is managed. if n x n x len(z) bytes doesn't fit in your memory, they will be very slow. In that case, looping is the best way.

Comment: n~12000, len(z)~100

Comment: I'm running it on a cluster node with 32 cores. The total ram is 124GB. And I have 1000 such 12K X 12K matrices I want to compute.

Comment: I edited it using Numba, it will be faster.

Comment: That was fantastic! Thank you kindly. It computes in at most half the time (and at best 5 times faster) and it also uses CPU power from idle processors in a node. The 'for' loop didn't do that, which made the whole thing slow

Comment: do you mind posting your earlier answers too, if not in the main part, then here in the comments? The np.einsum and the other one.

Comment: @PrasadMani I added them